# Function that counts unique characters in an array

Tags: c++, function, loops, boolean

I want to have a function that counts number of unique characters. If for example i have `aabbcc` i want it to return `3`. If `aab` i want to have `2` and so on....

My attempt was to construct a function that is checking whether number appeared previously and then us it as `if` condition.

My code is:

```
bool firstocc(char* t, int i){
    for(int j = 0;j < i;j++){
        if(t[j] == t[i]) return false;
            return true;    
    }    
}

int h(char* t){
    int c=0;
    for(int i=0; t[i+1]!=0;i++){
        if(firstocc(t,i)){
            c++;
        }

        return c;
    }

}


int main()
{
    cout<< h("aabbc");
}
```

Function always returns zero. What is wrong with it?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Did you try using the debugger?

Comment: I have tried everything you are talking about and still i am not able to solve my problem. That is why i decided to write here

Comment: if input always like this `aabbbccc` then you do not need to scan, jsut count when symbol changes. And parameter must be `const char *` not `char *` if you want to pass string literals

Comment: Input as well could be 11aab.

Comment: I mean if it cannot be `aba` but the same symbols grouped together

Comment: no it does not have to be like that it could be baab as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the braces in both functions `firstocc` and `h` (maybe because a bad indentation, always try take care with indent your code properly, not for compiler but for yourself), and with the loop of function `h` where the condition was `t[i+1] != 0` and should be `t[i] != 0` (to include the last char).

The code should be:

```
bool firstocc(char* t, int i){
    for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
        if(t[j]==t[i])
            return false;
    return true;
}

int h(char* t){
    int c=0;
    for(int i=0; t[i]!=0;i++)
        if(firstocc(t,i)){
            c++;
        }
    return c;
}
```

I tested it with `"aabbcddddeaa"` and it returns 5.

Comment: Looks like we got the same answer!

Answer (score 2):

if your string always follows the pattern, when the same symbol grouped together, then count is simple:

```
int count_unique( const std::string &str )
{
     char last = 0;
     int count = 0;
     for( char c : str )
         if( last != c ) {
             last = c;
             ++count;
         }
     return count;
}
```

if they are not mandatory grouped use `std::set`:

```
int count_unique( const std::string &str )
{
    return std::set<char>( str.begin(), str.end() ).size();
}
```

if `std::set` is not allowed and no grouping then use first one slightly modified:

```
int count_unique( std::string str )
{
     std::sort( str.begin(), str.end() );
     char last = 0;
     int count = 0;
     for( char c : str )
         if( last != c ) {
             last = c;
             ++count;
         }
     return count;
}
```

Comment: But if they are not is it possible without use of std::set ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an extra closing brace after the line 'c++'.

Then remove the extra brace immediately following 'return c;'

You also have some unbalanced brackets in the top part. I think the working version of your code is this:

```
bool firstocc(char* t, int i){
    for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
        if(t[j]==t[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int h(char* t){
    int c=0;
    for(int i=0; t[i]!=0;i++){
        if(firstocc(t,i)){
            c++;
        }
    }
    return c;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::cout<< h("aac") <<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Still wrong i am not able to receive a correct answer. e.g. if i have "aabbc" it returns 2 whereas it should return 3

Comment: Appreciate that :)